# HowTo Track an E-Mail on it's voyage

Tags: security, email

Is there any way to track an E-Mail during it's "journey"?

A friend of mine believes, that People the sports club he is involved with and where he has an E-Mail address, is reading the E-Mails of all functionaries. Since they host the server themselves the technical possibility are there. Illegal however, since they did not sign a waver. (different topic anyhow)

Is there any method could be used to track / check if someone is reading the emails before they reach their destination?

I was thinking about sending an email that loads an external image which I could then track where it was loaded. This only works under limited circumstances though - any better ideas?

Comment: No, there is not.  Your better idea would be encryption, such as PGP/GPG/whatever you favor.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't tell if anyone is eavesdropping on your mails sent through SMTP if it is done properly. Any server administrator in the path of your message (it may travel through several hops) is technically able to copy away the content without any visible traces.

The idea of hiding an image reference in the HTML part of the message will only work for very unsophisticated eavesdroppers who are careless enough to read the mail using a mail client rendering HTML *and* loading external images (most clients don't by default).

You obviously could check if mail content is leaking by means of social engineering: submit an interesting ("hot") piece of information exclusively via private email and make sure it has no other way to leak. If people start acting as if they are aware of this piece of information, you will have a clue. Repeat the procedure for better accuracy.

While you can't check if your mail is being eavesdropped on (or even if its contents are being changed in transit), you can *prevent* eavesdropping and unnoticeable changes by adding cryptographic signatures and encryption for all outgoing mail. S/MIME and PGP are common mechanisms to do so, but both require that the recipient has the technical ability to decode the message and check the signature and has set up a key pair and published the public key beforehand.

The bottom line: if you don't trust your mail hoster, encrypt your email.

Comment: I don't think the eavesdroppers are very sophisticated, but you are right - most emailclients dont load external images. That's why I asked the question since that solution didn't look very promising to me. However your post gave me the nice idea of combining the social engineering aspect and the tracker-beacon-image idea.
There could be an E-mail that references a link to an external "important document" which I can track. (honeypot)
Or maybe a "new password" eMail for our internal systems with a bogus account. Not quite what I really need but better than nothing I guess.

Answer (score 5):

Every email is like a plaintext postcard. The only solution to your primary problem is end-to-end encryption. Look for GPG.

However, you are asking to 1) track the email on it's journey 2) find out who's reading your mails. These are 2 different questions and I have 2 discouraging answers for you.

---

To find out the path, which the mails has taken to travel from source to destination is deposited in every mail, in it's header. I took a more complex from a mailing list with many different hosts (most of them not facing the public net):

```
Received: from scipy.org (unknown [216.62.213.231])
    by hostname.example.net (Postfix) with ESMTP id 0ED6022427
    for <user@example.net>; Fri,  5 Dec 2014 14:30:18 +0100 (CET)
Received: from scipy.org (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
    by scipy.org (Postfix) with ESMTP id CA29E327C6;
    Fri,  5 Dec 2014 07:30:07 -0600 (CST)
Received: from plane.gmane.org (plane.gmane.org [80.91.229.3])
    by scipy.org (Postfix) with ESMTP id 1D4FD32728
    for <numpy-discussion@scipy.org>; Fri,  5 Dec 2014 07:30:05 -0600 (CST)
Received: from list by plane.gmane.org with local (Exim 4.69)
    (envelope-from <gcpng-numpy-discussion@m.gmane.org>)
    id 1XwsxN-00085o-F1
    for numpy-discussion@scipy.org; Fri, 05 Dec 2014 14:30:03 +0100
Received: from c-107-3-18-170.hsd1.me.comcast.net ([107.3.18.170])
    by main.gmane.org with esmtp (Gmexim 0.1 (Debian))
    id 1AlnuQ-0007hv-00
    for <numpy-discussion@scipy.org>; Fri, 05 Dec 2014 14:30:01 +0100
Received: from rnelsonchem by c-107-3-18-170.hsd1.me.comcast.net with local
    (Gmexim 0.1 (Debian)) id 1AlnuQ-0007hv-00
    for <numpy-discussion@scipy.org>; Fri, 05 Dec 2014 14:30:01 +0100
```

I obfuscated only the domains in the last part (on the top), where the destination server is (in this case it was mine). I will not explain how to read is, as most of it is self-explanatory and other questions and answers dealt with this already.

This is the path, the mail took. But you can't use it for your purpose, as on **every server mentioned and every connection between them** (even if encrypted, in most cases. I'm not aware of any mail servers checking certificates..) **can read the content of the mail**.

---

Now, to find out who's read the mail: I don't know any possibility to get that information. Some common and easy ways of the various possibilities to read a mail:

- Read the mail from the file system. As every mail is somehow saved as file on the servers, a server admin can simply read it.
- On the user side, any user knowing the password of his IMAP/POP-account can log in as him an read the mail. Apart from the read-flag, there's no trace left by them, at least not accessible for another user.
- An admin can send a copy of every mail destined to the victim to a mail account of the eavesdropper. In your situation, you also can't find that out, except the attacker sends a response :)

I don't list a tracking pixel here, as all mail clients I know, do suppress automatic loading of remote content for privacy reasons. However, you can suck it and see.

Comment: I am not looking to secure the communication but prove wrongdoings.
Maybe copies of the emails are being diverted but since these would never reach me I won't be able to tell from the header. I am pretty sure they are being read on the server.